# Firefox strange behaviour when working with javascript on an iframe

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe, behavior

i've met a strange behaviour in Firefox with this simple script:

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.setTimeout(function(){
                var ifr=document.createElement("iframe");
                ifr.src="about:blank";
                document.body.appendChild(ifr);
                var doc=ifr.contentDocument || ifr.contentWindow.document,
                    div=doc.createElement("div");
                div.innerHTML="test";
                window.setTimeout(function(){
                    doc.body.appendChild(div);
                },500);
            },500);
        </script>
    </head>
  </html>
```

This piece of code creates a blank iframe and appends it to the body of the current page, then it creates a div element that contains a simple text and appends it to the body of the iframe.

In every browser (IE, Safari, Chrome, Opera) it works, but in Firefox (i'm using the version 3.6.3) the div does not appear inside the iframe and no error is thrown.

I think that there must be some stupid error somewhere but i can't find it, have you got some idea?

PS: those `window.setTimeout` are just a simple way to make sure that the dom is loaded in the page and in the iframe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to wrap the retrieval of the iframe doc in the timeout.

```
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            var doc=ifr.contentWindow.document || ifr.contentDocument;
            var div=doc.createElement("div");
            div.innerHTML="test";
            doc.body.appendChild(div);
        },500);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/xeGSe/1/

Comment: I knew that there was an easy explanation:) thanks this works perfectly

Comment: that isn't an explanation, it's a workaround for the core problem that it doesn't solve completely.

Comment: I did try rewriting it using jQuery but still had to use a timeout. Any ideas - http://jsfiddle.net/xeGSe/2/?

Comment: It's really not the way the problem should be solved, you should use @roryf solution

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a timing issue that your `setTimeout` calls aren't catching. Your better off using `onload` events to ensure elements are truly available (`DOMReady` would be better but not as easy in IE). Try this:

```
document.body.onload = function() {
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.src = "about:blank";
    iframe.onload = function() {
        var doc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document,
            div = doc.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML="test";
        doc.body.appendChild(div);
    }
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
}
```